# Verb sequence when used with “Will” or “Shall”

Tags: verbs, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

In the following sentence, is "telecast" a verb, or something else?

> The Awards will be **telecast** on Saturday at 8:00 PM.

I am a little confused about verb structure/sequence.  In particular, in what order should verbs be used, in sentences with “will” or “shall”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customary word order in a declarative statement is: **will *verb***. **Shall** works the same way. For example:

> She **will pay** you next week.
>
> I **shall return**. *[Famous (mis-)quotation of General Douglas MacArthur when he was forced to [leave troops behind](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/macarthur-leaves-corregidor) on an island during World War II.]*

The verb after **will** or **shall** always takes its infinitive form. Notice that the first sentence has **pay**, not **pays**, even though the subject is **She**.

When you make the verb passive, you use the past-participle form of the verb and put **be** in front of it. **Be** takes its infinitive form, and follows **will** or **shall** as in your sentence:

> The Awards **will be telecast** on Saturday at 8:00 PM.
>
> The Awards ceremony **will be forgotten** in two weeks. *[Notice the past participle **forgotten**, not **forget** or **forgot**.]*
>
> The people who stole our cars **shall be punished**.

**Telecast** is an irregular verb, like **cast**. Its past participle is the same as its infinitive. (Very few English verbs are like that.)

---

In a question, normal word order is reversed: the **will** or **shall** goes before the subject:

> **Will** she **pay** you next week?
>
> **Shall** I **return**?
>
> **Will** the Awards **be telecast** on Saturday at 8:00 PM?
>
> **Will** the Awards ceremony **be forgotten** in two weeks?
>
> **Shall** the people who stole our cars **be punished**?

Answer (score 2):

Here, **telecast** is being used as a verb. The sentence is in passive form.

If you were to use it as a noun, the sentence structure could be something like :
**The Award show telecast will air on Saturday at 8 PM.**